# How to get at runtime the filepath of the servlet class generated fom a JSP?

Tags: java, jsp, caching, weblogic, jrebel

**Question:** How can I get at runtime the filepath from where the server is loading the servlet class that was generated for a given JSP file? For instance, I have a JSP file research_form_manage.jsp that is accessible at a certain URL and I want to log the filepath for the generated __research_form_manage.java that is handling my request (it will be in a cache on the server probably).

**Context:** I have a web application deployed on WebLogic 12c (that I automatically deploy using JRebel from IntelliJ). Sometimes I get errors because the JSPs are loaded from some cache and are outdated. I manually cleared the cache locations I know (tmp\ and cache\ from under my_domain\server... and then restarted the server) but the file is still loaded from the cache.

I found [this idea](http://sandeepseshan.blogspot.be/2009/12/weblogic-server-flush-application-cache.html) about how to locate where cached classes are loaded from and I would like to log the location of the jsp translated servlet using somthing like
`...class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation();`

Answer (score 0):

I found a way that seems to work, by adding in the JSP file this line:
`<%= getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation() %>`

The class is in the domain\servers...\tmp folder that I deleted, so I don't know where the old version of the jsp was coming from.

This code does what I needed but it's not that nice because it means I have to modify the JSP and then remember to clean it before pushing. I was thinking initially to put a breakpoint somewhere and add a watch with an expression that would give this filepath based on the jsp file name.

So if anybody has a better way, please share.